# why converting char to bits doesn't return correct value

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I am trying to read a file in binary format. The characters then is converted to bits. when I print the bits the value is not correct.
For example: character value 1 which should show 00000001 is shown 00110001.
would appropriate for some help.

Below is my code:

```
bitset<8> ToBits(unsigned char byte)
{
    return bitset<8>(byte);
}
/* Data.dat file consist of "1727287561749074585503063440519377
174986245180164461301183362661153044730118336266115304473011833626611530447"*/


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
    char buffer[100];
    ifstream myFile("data.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
    myFile.read(buffer, 100);
    if (stat("data.dat", &results) == 0)
    {
    cout <<"Size of the file is " <<results.st_size <<" bytes" <<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Size could not be aquired" << endl;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100;)
    {

    bitset<8> my_bset = ToBits(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char&>(buffer[i]));
    cout << "char (" <<buffer[i] <<")" <<"  ";
    cout << my_bset[7] << my_bset[6] << my_bset[5] << my_bset[4] << my_bset[3] << my_bset[2] << my_bset[1] << my_bset[0] << endl;
    i++;
    }
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Size of the file is 109 bytes
char (1)  00110001 // The char value is 1 but the output is 00110001 which
char (7)  00110111 // in decimal is 49?
char (2)  00110010
char (7)  00110111
char (2)  00110010
char (8)  00111000
char (7)  00110111
char (5)  00110101
char (6)  00110110
char (1)  00110001
char (7)  00110111
char (4)  00110100
char (9)  00111001
char (0)  00110000
char (7)  00110111
char (4)  00110100
char (5)  00110101
char (8)  00111000
char (5)  00110101
char (5)  00110101
char (0)  00110000
char (3)  00110011
char (0)  00110000
char (6)  00110110
char (3)  00110011
char (4)  00110100
char (4)  00110100
char (0)  00110000
char (5)  00110101
char (1)  00110001
char (9)  00111001
char (3)  00110011
char (7)  00110111
char (7)  00110111
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the print out is correct.  It is printing the binary ASCII value for the character.  The ASCII value for 1 is 49 and the binary for that is 0011 0001.  Your program is working.